# Generating large amounts of test data using sets of known values?

Tags: mysql, excel, test-data

I am using [Mockaroo](http://www.mockaroo.com) and Excel to create and edit some CSV files that will be inserted into a MySQL database as test data. I have a file named `student_takes_module` with columns `module_ID` and `student_ID`.

There are 10000 student IDs and 500 modules. The spec for the system this is part of requires that between 1 and 400 students are registered to each module (hence `student_takes_module`).

Is there a way I can pair up random `student_ID` and `module_ID` values in keeping with this spec?

Comment: Have you stored the maximum number of students for each module in the database?

Comment: I haven't - for the purposes of the database I'm not sure that will be required if I can generate the data correctly? The DB is needed only as a sample data source for a timetabling algorithm written elsewhere. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method, that is approximate and computationally painful.  It starts by assigning each module a number of students.  Then it chooses students for that module randomly.

```
insert into student_takes_module(module_id, student_id)
    select m.module_id, s.student_id
    from (select m.*, 10 + rand() * 350 as numstudents
          from modules m
         ) m cross join
         students s cross join
         (select count(*) as totalstudents) const
    where rand() < m.numstudents/const.totalstudents;
```

The `350` instead of `400` is because the use of `rand()` in this context is approximate.  The use of `10` is because I think that if you have a minimum of 10 students, then you will probably get at least one student for that class as you cycle through the data.

This approach will be processing 10,000*500 = 5,000,000 rows to generate the test data.  However, the calculations are not so bad (`rand()` has a reputation for bad performance but that is because of confusion between the function call and `order by rand()`).  You can test the performance by putting `limit` at the end to see how long it takes it to generate 10 rows, then 1000 rows, then 10000, then all the rows you need.

Comment: Run Randomize Timer() each time before you generate a random number to improve randomness.

Comment: I accepted your answer as it seems to be the most complete solution. I have added my own answer as a quicker way of achieving similar (but less comprehensive) results

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to work with the `RANDBETWEEN` function in Excel to randomly pick values from `module_ID` to fill a new column alongside `student_ID`s

Alternatively Mockaroo will accept all 500 module_IDs as a custom list which it could assign to randomly generated student_IDs.

The downside to these methods is that the students will be spread very evenly among all modules.